# Passing an in input argument to hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink, hypertarget

I have a text with many abbreviations and I want to have a simple command which takes the reader to the original definition of each abbreviation.

I can do this in a standard way as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
   Text on page 1. 
   \newpage

   Defining \hypertarget{abbv:cg}{center of gravity} on page 2.
   \newpage

   Text on page 3
   \newpage

   Link on page 4 - \hyperlink{abbv:cg}{CG}
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to have a command of the type `\ablink{abbreviation}`, which takes in an abbreviation and uses it to form the label to `\hyperlink{}{}`. I tried doing it as:

```
\newcommand{\ablink}[1]{\hyperlink{abbv:\lowercase{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
   Text on page 1. 
   \newpage

   Defining \hypertarget{abbv:cg}{center of gravity} on page 2.
   \newpage

   Text on page 3
   \newpage

   Link on page 4 - \ablink{CG}

\end{document}
```

using `\lowercase{#1}` with the hope to have some robustness in the event the abbreviation is specified in non-lower case. This command sends me to page 1.

I tried removing `\lowercase`:

```
\newcommand{\ablink}[1]{\hyperlink{abbv:{#1}}{#1}}
\begin{document}
   Text on page 1. 
   \newpage

   Defining \hypertarget{abbv:cg}{center of gravity} on page 2.
   \newpage

   Text on page 3
   \newpage

   Link on page 4 - \ablink{CG}
\end{document}
```

but this didn't work either, so it seems the issue comes from dynamically specifying the label.

Comment: `\newcommand{\ablink}[1]{\lowercase{\hyperlink{abbv:#1}}{#1}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're just using ASCII characters for your abbreviations,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\abdef}[2]{\lowercase{\hypertarget{abbv:#1}}{#2}}
\newcommand{\ablink}[1]{\lowercase{\hyperlink{abbv:#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
Text on page 1.
\newpage

Defining \abdef{CG}{center of gravity} on page 2.
\newpage

Text on page 3
\newpage

Link on page 4 - \ablink{CG}

Link on page 4 - \ablink{cg}

\end{document}
```

Can you see? `\lowercase` will only act on `#1`, reinserting the modified tokens before evaluating `\hypertarget` or `\hyperlink`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason to why `\lowercase{#1}` wouldn't work?

Comment: @PeterHristov Because it is not expandable and so the lowercasing would happen too late, if it didn't break `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add braces around #1 and use also uppercase letters in the target:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\ablink}[1]{\hyperlink{abbv:#1}{#1}}
\begin{document}
   Text on page 1.
   \newpage

   Defining \hypertarget{abbv:CG}{center of gravity} on page 2.
   \newpage

   Text on page 3
   \newpage

   Link on page 4 - \hyperlink{abbv:CG}{CG}

   Link on page 4 - \ablink{CG}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the answer which matched my original goal more closely.